# Grafana & Prometheus: get target from a job_name

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I need in grafana's dashboard to get a list of the targets (activemq01, activemq02, activemq03) from a specfic job_name (activemq-job).

Actually I can get on my dashboard only the job_name but I can't filter by target.

Prometheus.yaml

```
  - job_name: activemq-job
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['activemq01:8060', 'activemq02:8060', 'activemq03:8060']
```

Dashboard.json

```
      {
        "allValue": null,
        "current": {},
        "datasource": "${DS_PROMETHEUS}",
        "definition": "label_values(job)",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": true,
        "index": -1,
        "label": null,
        "multi": true,
        "name": "Component",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(job)",
        "refresh": 2,
        "regex": "(activemq-job)",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 0,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in the variable definition:

```
Query = label_values(instance)
```